# Get date for [Nth] [DAYNAME] of [MONTH] from numeric indexes WITHOUT converting to a string?

Tags: php, date, datetime

Assuming you have four numeric variables:

```
$Index=2; // 1-6, 2 is the second occurrence
$Dow=3; // 0-6, 3 is Wednesday
$Month=3; // 1-12, 3 is March
$Year=2016;
```

Is there a simple way to use those **numbers** to create or modify a `DateTime` object to represent that specific date? For example, with the variables above, it would be the specific date of the 2nd Wednesday in March of 2016.

I know that you can do this with `strtotime` or the `DateTime` constructor **if** you have it written out as a string already. There are other answers on here that deal with that.

But since we have numeric indexes, it seems stupid to create a function that converts numbers to a human readable string that then gets passed into a string parser to generate a date.

So the question is, is there a way to use **strictly numeric** variables with the `DateTime` object **without** having to first convert it to a human readable string to get a relative date like the 2nd(2) Wednesday(3) of March(3)?

I'm looking for something like:

```
$oDate = new DateTime();
$oDate->setFromWeekdayOfMonthIndex($Position,$DOWNum,$MonthNum,$Year);
```

**UPDATE #1**

Just to clarify the question a bit, this does what I want, but is a long/silly way of doing it:

```
$oMonthDate = new DateTime();
$oMonthDate->setDate($Year, $MonthNum, 1);

$oFormater = new NumberFormatter('en-US', NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT);
$oFormater->setTextAttribute(NumberFormatter::DEFAULT_RULESET,"%spellout-ordinal");

$String  = $oFormater->format($Position).' ';
$String .= date('l', strtotime('Sunday +'.$DOW.' days')). ' of ';            
$String .= $oMonthDate->format('F'). ' '.$Year;

$oFinalDate = new DateTime($String); // "second Tuesday of January 2016"
```

Comment: you can use [gmmktime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmmktime.php) or [mktime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php). You can also use [DateTime::setDate](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.setdate.php)

Comment: For format something like `2nd Wednesday of March` you may have to find the date yourselves or use [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

Comment: Doesn't look like there's any way to do it. Yes, it's a bit stupid, but all the necessary PHP interfaces are stringy ones. Even trying to do it longhand using date math I ran into the fact that the only `DateInterval` constructor takes a string.